# Which Samsung smartphone models support LTE and are not susceptible to "sudden death syndrome"?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.4-kitkat, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Does anyone know which Samsung smartphone models support LTE and are not susceptible to "sudden death syndrome"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any Samsung is going to be susceptible to "SDS" (Sudden death syndrome)

## Because Samsung is just "high quality stuffs".

- For a point of reference, I am a smartphone data recovery/Mod/Repair technician, and I see SDS and Memory errors almost exclusively in samsung devices.

The only exceptions were Damaged by Water.